# How to display mysql data in html rows

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter and I want to display a list of cities in multiple columns in html like this where i can just adjust the number of items inside the `<ul>` tag and then generate another `<ul>` tag for the next column

```
----------------
City name 1     City name 5    City name 9
City name 2     City name 6    City name 10
City name 3     City name 7
City name 4     City name 8
-------------------
```

I dont know how to make it display like that but here's my current code that just display everything in 1 column.

```
<ul>
<?php 
      foreach($row_city as $city):      
        echo "<li>".anchor("#",$city->city_name)."</li>";
      endforeach; 
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use tables. Simply use this code:

```
$i = 0;
echo "<ul>";
foreach($row_city as $city):      
    if ($i != 0 && $i%4 == 0) {
       echo "</ul><ul>";
    }
    echo "<li>".anchor("#",$city->city_name)."</li>";
    $i++;
endforeach; 
echo "</ul>";
```

and just float the lists next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to display it inside a table like that with that html code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
     <ul>
        <li>element1</li>
        <li>element1</li>
        <li>element1</li>
     </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
     <ul>
        <li>element2</li>
        <li>element2</li>
        <li>element2</li>
     </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
     <ul>
        <li>element2</li>
        <li>element2</li>
        <li>element2</li>
     </ul>
    </td>
</table>
```

And then you must update your code to make it work with more column.
Here an example of php code that show that kind of output:

```
<table>
<?php
echo '<td><ul>';
$j =4;
for($i = 0; $i<10; $i++ ){
if($j==0){
echo '</ul></td><td><ul>';
$j=4;
}
echo "<li>".$i."</li>";
$j--;
}
echo '</ul></td>';
?>
```

You can adapt it to your problem (try to replace the for with your foreach).